# Input Validation - Only Integers?

Tags: java

> I'm working on a project where the Java code must find the total,
>   average, etc. of exam scores. It reads the scores from an external
>   file.

I've been trying for hours to find a way to edit my code so that it ignores any data in the file that is not an integer between 0-100. But I can't. Checked all the questions and answers on Stack Overflow, and I can't find any answers that would help my specific situation. Here's the while loop of my code that I'm trying to work with:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);

   while (reader.hasNext())
   {
       String line = reader.nextLine();
       nextScore = Integer.parseInt(line);
       System.out.println(nextScore);
       sum = nextScore + sum;
       totalNumberOfScores++;



       if (nextScore > maxScore)
       {
           maxScore = nextScore;
       }

       else if (nextScore < minScore)
       {
           minScore = nextScore;
       }

       if (nextScore >= A)
       {
           countA++;
       }

       else if (nextScore >= B)
       {
           countB++;
       }

       else if (nextScore >= C)
       {
           countC++;
       }

       else if (nextScore >= D)
       {
           countD++;
       }

       else 
       {
           countF++;
       }
   }

    reader.close();
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Show the format of file that you are reading.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing

Comment: The problem I am facing is that I need my program to ignore any data from the external file that is not an integer, but I can't. As for the format of the file, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isInteger(line)){
  nextScore = Integer.parse(line);
}

public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(s);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        } catch(NullPointerException e) {
            return false;
        }
        // only got here if we didn't return false
        return true;
    }
```

then you can do this

```
boolean isNumber = false;
for(int i = 0; i < line.length; i++){
 try{
  Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(line.charAt(i)));
 }catch(Exception e){
  isNumber = false;
  break;
 }
}
if(isNumber){
 Integer.parse(line);
}
```

or even

```
boolean isNumber = true;
try{
 Integer.praseInt(line);
}catch(Exception e){
 isNumber = false;
}
if(isNumber){
 //everthing else
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, we haven't covered classes and methods yet. I'm getting familiar with how they work, but my professor would probably take points off for doing it this way.

Comment: thats alright i added some other options unless u cant use a try{}catch{} since that probably is later on too

Comment: Years, later, now that I know what I'm doing, I'm a little embarrassed at having made this question. But yes, this is a valid implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close` the `Scanner` when through reading. Next, you need to define your `min`, `max`, `total` and `lines` count outside the loop. You could default `min` to the maximum possible value, and `max` to the minimum; then use `Math.max(int,int)` and `Math.min(int,int)` to set the max and min respectively. Then, you need to validate that you read an `int` and that is in the correct range before processing it as input. Something like,

```
try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(file)) {
  int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
  int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int total = 0;
  int lines = 0;
  int countA = 0, countB = 0, countC = 0, countD = 0, countF = 0;
  while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = reader.nextLine();
    try {
      int nextScore = Integer.parseInt(line);
      if (nextScore >= 0 && nextScore <= 100) {
        min = Math.min(nextScore, min);
        max = Math.max(nextScore, max);
        total += nextScore;
        lines++;
        if (nextScore >= A) {
          countA++;
        } else if (nextScore >= B) {
          countB++;
        } else if (nextScore >= C) {
          countC++;
        } else if (nextScore >= D) {
          countD++;
        } else {
          countF++;
        }
      }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
  }
  System.out.printf("Min: %d, Max: %d, Total: %d, Lines: %d, Average: %.2f%n",
      min, max, total, lines, total / (float) lines);
  System.out.printf("%d As, %d Bs, %d Cs, %d Ds, %d Fs", countA, countB, 
     countC, countD, countF);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```